# Calling methods from the array doesnt change the object

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I try to call a method from the object inside an array, the change doesn't persist through the rest of the code.

Through some search I saw that the `get()` method from the array needs to return the variable by reference, but when I try doing that other exceptions appear.
So I tried using this:

```
template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::get(int pos)
{
    if (pos > this->index || pos < 0)
    {
        return T&() ;
    }
    return &this->array[pos];
}
```

But I got the error:

> error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ')', expected 'Expression'

I'm a newbie in C++ and any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `T&()` is not a valid syntax. A reference cannot be default-constructed, it must be bound to a valid object.

Comment: References are not pointers. `&this->array[pos];` is a pointer, not a reference. There is no such thing as "empty reference", your method of handling out-of-bounds errors won't quite work.

Comment: Then now i'm completely lost on what to do. I need to find a method that doesnt create a copy of the object inside the array when i use get()

Comment: `if (pos > this->index || pos < 0)` if this condition holds, there is no object to return, so you should not return any. You need to throw an exception instead.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to *declare* the template type T at the beginning of your function.

```cpp
template <typename T>
```

Second, you **cannot** return a reference to a temporary variable like you're doing here. (It's not even proper syntax, like Igor commented.)

```cpp
return T&();
```

You should probably throw an exception instead.

```cpp
throw std::out_of_range("Attempted to access out of bounds");
```

Third, you can remove `this->` from your code. The function already gives you access to your struct's fields.

This leaves you with this valid code snippet here.

```cpp
template <typename T> T &Vector<T>::get(int pos) {
    if (pos > index || pos < 0) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Attepted to access out of bounds");
    }
    return array[pos];
}
```

Comment: First off: Not if the entire class is templated (which I would expect Vector<T> to be)